# Chef code block, how to "not_if" using output of "stat"

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

OK, I am new to chef and frankly a novice at programming and even worse come from a powershell/.NET background so take it easy!
The idea of this execute block is to not run if the owner/group of the folder/file output is 'root wheel'

```
  execute 'set_owner' do
    command 'sudo chown -R root:wheel /applications/'
    not_if { stat -c "%U %G" /mydir/ } = 'root wheel'
  end
```

The idea is there, but the exact syntax isn't correct.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't do this using an external command, I mean you could but it's a lot harder. Using plain Ruby code is easier:

```
not_if { ::File.stat('/mydir').uid == 0 && ::File.stat('/mydir').gid == 0 }
```